# How to make a global variable in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I have a Mysql login system in Visual Basic , and I want to store the username in a global variable after a succesful login but when the app will close I want that variable to be deleted.. can you show me some example? I'm a beginner at visual basic.

Comment: Just do nothing.  All variables disappear when an app closes.

Comment: You need to define your environment -- is this a win form app or an asp.net app?

Answer (score 2):

If you're developing on Windows, then use the Windows Registry to persist the value.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289494(v=vs.71).aspx for more details, and examples.

Take care if caching a password though; you'll need to encrypt that.

Comment: I want to have something like a Temporary Variable that is defined only per one session.. I mean, like $_SESSION['username'] from PHP.

Comment: Presumably you have a class that models the main application. Just have your variable as member data of that class. I'd still use the registry if I were you though: to save the user from having to type their login every time they use your app. The registry has a HKEY_CURRENT_USER hive which means that different users on a computer see a different registry database; i.e. separate users can have separate logins.

Comment: I have 2 forms.. LoginForm1 and IndexForm, LoginForm1 is the startup form and IndexForm is hidden by default, if the login is succesful in LoginForm1 then the IndexForm will be shown, and I still don't understant how to store that member name.. the beginning of VB for me is very bad for now... I wanted to use that member name to query some data from Mysql in the IndexForm with "SELECT * FROM members WHERE name='..'"  but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2):

Just create a class (in your project) that will not be instantiated right...and then have a variable in that class with access modifier
     *Public Shared*. 
Like for me I made a class called Globals and in it was a variable called  *currentUser* .
So to access the variable from any class I just had *Globals.currentUser =txtUser.Text*
And declare it like  *Public Shared currentUser as String*

Answer (score 1):

Try this, in your form file outside of the main class, or in a separate module file:

```
Public Module Globals
    Public UserName As String = ""
End Module
```

Now you can access it in any code throughout your project.  It will dispose when the app is closed.  If you wanted to make doubly sure, even though it would be redundant, add this to the main form that closes the whole app:

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
    UserName = ""
End Sub
```